# mysql sorting and between using a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am executing a query in which i use joins. In that i have used a subquery which will total amount. i want to sort by the result of the subquery  like the following.

```
"select users.*, (select sum(amount) as camount from donation where donation.uid=users.id) as camount from users where users.confirmed=1  and camount between 3 and 5 order by camount";
```

I get an error: 1064.

How to query by sotring using the result of a sub query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what triggers the error you get but moving the sub-select to an inner join should yield the same results.

**SQL Statement**

```
select  users.*
        , donation.camount
from    users 
        INNER JOIN (
          select  uid
                  , sum( amount ) as camount 
          from    donation 
          group by
                  uid
        ) donation ON donation.uid = users.id
where   users.confirmed = 1  
        and donation.camount between 3 and 5 
order by 
        donation.camount
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

select users.*, (select sum(d.amount) from donation d, users u  where d.uid=u.id) as camount from users where users.confirmed=1  and camount between 3 and 5 order by camount

Comment: Not entirely what OP wants. The query gets the total amount of *all* users for *each* record.